# Programmatically change between two resource files

Tags: android, android-resources

Is there a way to change/pick which of the resource files is being used if you have like `colors.xml` and `colors_inverted.xml` and you want Activity A to use one and Activity B to use another?

Comment: Use them how? `getResources()` or `R.color` doesn't give you any file options

Comment: why do you want to do that? is that necessaryy to know?

Comment: Ideally, you would define **styles** for each Activity

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I didn't explain it as I should have, actually I wanted to allow the user to change between two color schemes and it seemed easier to switch between two color resource files that had the same color names but different values and update the entire app rather than changing themes for the app, toolbar and so on.

Comment: @cricket_007 I wanted to allow the user to change between two color schemes and it seemed easier to switch between two color resource files that had the same color names but different values and update the entire app rather than changing themes for the app, toolbar and so on.

Comment: Again, you can't dynamically define a resource file at any level than the View or Activity. If you want some selection mechanism, store values in a database or some other way

Comment: @cricket_007 I got that, I simply wanted to explain what I initially waned. I already started defining styles and changing between those. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate Theme with different colors for different activities. Using two color files is not possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.. I wanted to allow the user to change between two color schemes and it seemed easier to switch between two color resource files that had the same color names but different values and update the entire app rather than changing themes for the app, toolbar and so on but it seems I will have to create separate themes...